# QGIS crashing when trying to change style attribute

Tags: qgis, postgis, csv

QGIS started crashing w Ver 2.18.3-1

If I open a project from a previous version it crashes w error QGIS bin has stopped working.

If opening only a new CSV file or postgresql DB layer it will load the new layer and crash when I attempt to open the properties of the layer.

I did re install ver 2.14  stable Corp release and can get project to open, but those projects will crash QGIS when opening the style attribute.

Has anyone one else experienced this or have a fix?

---

"qgis-ltr-bin.exe has stopped working"

---

Windows 10 Enterprise Error log:

Faulting application name: qgis-ltr-bin.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x58799528
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.14393.447, time stamp: 0x5819bc32
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000004839c
Faulting process id: 0x23dc
Faulting application start time: 0x01d28853a2c42cdc
Faulting application path: C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\bin\qgis-ltr-bin.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: acab3985-0a94-4541-8c50-66053a0995b8
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: What is the precise wording of the error message that you are seeing?